# Tamil language input system broken on upgrade to Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: upgrade, ibus

I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic) three days ago; i also installed updates yesterday (2023 Nov 21).

I have IBus 1.5.29-rc1 installed.

Since the upgrade I've been experiencing problems typing certain characters of the Tamil alphabet (ibus-m17n). These problems weren't there until I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10 (from 23.04).

### I need to describe the problem in Tamil because it won't make sense otherwise.

இந்த problem description-ஐத் தட்டச்சுச் செய்கையில் வேறு சில சிக்கல்களும் எழுந்தன; அவற்றைக் கவனமாகப் பிரித்துத் தொகுக்கவேண்டும். (இவற்றில் சில சிக்கல்கள் ஒவ்வொரு முறையும் வெளிப்படுவதில்லை என்பது கூடுதல் தொல்லை!)

இவையனைத்தும் இப்போது புதிதாக முளைத்துள்ள சிக்கல்கள்.

### இப்போதைக்கு இரண்டுடன் நிறுத்திக்கொள்கிறேன். பிற புதுச் சிக்கல்கள் எதிர்ப்படுகையில் அவற்றைத் தெளிவாக வரையறுக்க முடிந்தால் அவற்றை இங்கு சேர்ப்பிக்கிறேன்.

சிக்கல் 1:

தமிழ் மெய் எழுத்துகளில் 'க்', உயிர்மெய் எழுத்துகளில் க, ங, ச, ஞ, ண, த, ப, ர, ல, வ, ற, ன ஆகியவற்றுக்கு அடுத்ததாக வேறொரு தமிழ் எழுத்தை அல்லது இடைவெளியைத் (space) தட்டச்சுச் செய்கையில் மேற்படி எழுத்துகளுக்கு முன்னதாக ஓர் இடைவெளி வருகிறது!

### அந்த எழுத்துகளுக்கு அடுத்ததாக (இடைவெளி அல்லாத பிற) நிறுத்தற் குறிகளைத் தட்டச்சுச் செய்கையில் இந்தச் சிக்கல் நேர்வதில்லை.

சிக்கல் 2:

இதைச் சில எடுத்துக்காட்டுகளைக் கொண்டு தான் விளக்க முடியும்.

"பிளன" என்று தட்டச்சுச் செய்துவிட்டு 'ன'-வை நீக்க முற்பட்டால் 'ள' அழிக்கப்படுகிறது. ஆனால் இது ஒவ்வொரு முறையும் இப்படி ஆவதில்லை! அடுத்தடுத்து 2-3 முறை இதைச் செய்தால் முதல் தடவை மட்டும் இப்படி ஆகிறது. பிறகு வேறு எதையேனும் (எ.கா. Enter/newline) தட்டச்சுச் செய்துவிட்டு மீண்டும் 'பிளன'-வைத் தட்டச்சுச் செய்து backspace-ஐ அழுத்தினால் 'ள' அழிபடுகிறது.

### "பிளன"-வைப் போலவே "பிறன", "பினட" உள்ளிட்டவற்றுக்கும் ஆகிறது.

Comment: Did you try to do: `sudo apt install fonts-noto-core`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did try that and got the following message:


**fonts-noto-core is already the newest version (20201225-2).

fonts-noto-core set to manually installed.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.**


I found a third problem today. (I've listed two problems above in the Tamil text portion.) When i hit backspace to delete the most recently typed character, instead of that character getting erased, the one before the last character gets mutilated (not erased); this is a variation on the second problem already mentioned.

Comment: I encountered another error today:
தொகுத்த_ என்று எழுதினால் தொகுத்_த என்று மாறிவிடுகிறது. ('த'-வுக்குப் பிறகு மீண்டும் ஒரு முறை underscore குறியை உள்ளிட்டு, முந்திய underscore குறியை அழிக்கவேண்டியுள்ளது!)